# Mirror material doesn't show reflections correctly

Tags: blender, mirror, tweak, reflections

I hope you all having good day.

To the point, I placed two mirrors, as shown below, but there is something wrong with the reflections, the reflection of front mirror and its image doesn't appear in the left hand mirror. I tried "Light Path" node but it didn't worked. any suggestions, please?

Thank you

[image: Mirrors reflections doesn't appear correctly]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of my problem, It was the checkbox "Fast GI Approximation" under Light Paths.
I was trying different presets, then suddenly It works, checked that checkbox again, and the mirror is black again.